# Copy multiple data from one sheet to other without Multiple vlookup

Tags: vlookup

I have two spreasheet and there are numbers of column on both the sheet, There is one common field (IDs) between those sheets. I can do multiple vlookup but would not like to do so because there are more than 20 columns needs to copied across from one sheet to other ..

would there be any other solution available to this problem pls

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at an index match combination where you have a column with the match formula then multiple index formulae that reference the match column. This should be more efficient since it only searches once per row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single formula whether with `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH`. In 2013, I believe you'd've had to use `{CSE}` for it. So write or paste your formula, highlight all the output cells, F2-Edit and `{CSE}` it to fill all the columns.

The way it works like this is that the column you want used for output can be specified by an `Array Constant` (still can in 2021, just don't need the `{CSE}` treatment). Those look like this:  `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`. That one would get you columns 1 through 9 of the source data.

You can do interesting things with an Array Constant too. If you put {1,5,5,5,7,9} you'd get column 5 three times in your output. And not columns 2, 3, 4, 6, and 8 at all. You can put them out of order too:  {5,1,4,7,3} would have column 5, then column 1, and so on.

So the `INDEX/MATCH` would look like this:

```
=INDEX(A1:I10,MATCH(D1,A1:A1,0),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
```

and `VLOOKUP()` like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($D$1,$A$1:$I$10,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},FALSE)
```

By the way, my experience with `VLOOKUP()` is that you can use an Array Constant for the lookup value, and so do several lookups at once (which is different from looking up something with multiple criteria), **OR** in the third parameter, but not in both places.

Also, directly writing it gives you the greatest control over it, but you can use the (2021 here) `SEQUENCE()` function or the older technique of ROW(1:9) to get the sequence (we think of it as just a sequence, but when Excel is calculating the formula piece by piece, it is using Array Constants made of the sequence, so it's still just an Array Constant.

You could even look in a table with, say, three columns and you first have to pick which of those three columns you are looking in. You cannot put formulaic things INSIDE an array constant, but you can use, say, an `IFS()` to select ONE of the three possible choices and pass out the appropriate hardcoded Array Constant.

Now that we have `XLOOKUP()` which can look from the end to the start of a range, this won't blow one's skirt up, but you can subtract the sequence you generate from a value to put the sequence in reverse order so you are effectively turning your table upside down to "search upwards" as it were.

Just lots of things you can do with this.